# Jquery hasClass doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that user can navigate through pages as follows:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="link bottom move" style="left:24em;"><a href="#iot"><span lang="tr">IOT NEDİR</span></a></li>
        <li class="link bottom move" style="left:12em;"><a href="#about"><span lang="tr">HAKKIMIZDA</span></a></li>
        <li class="link bottom move"><a href="#contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a></li>
        <li class="link bottom move" style="right:12em;"><a href="#solutions"><span lang="tr">ÇÖZÜMLERİMİZ</span></a></li>
        <li class="link bottom move" style="right:24em;"><a href="#products"><span lang="tr">ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

There is an image which user can zoom on IOT NEDİR page. The problem is I would like to initialize zoom feature when user navigates to the page.

Here is the related HTML:

```
<section class="active" style="left: 0px; z-index: 2;" id="iot" data-direction="from-right">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">IOT NEDİR</span>
            </h1>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                    <p class="iot-font" lang="tr">Nesnelerin İnternet'i (Internet of Things, kısaca IoT), fiziksel nesnelerin birbirleriyle veya daha büyük sistemlerle bağlantılı olduğu iletişim ağıdır. Nesnelerin tekil anahtar (unique identifier) ile işaretlenerek İnternet altyapısı üzerinden birlikte çalışabilmesi ve bu sayede küçük parçaların toplamından daha büyük değerler oluşturulması öngörülmüştür. Nesnelerin İnternet'i açısından, nesne kavramı oldukça geniş bir anlama sahiptir. Her türlü izleme cihazları, sensörler, biochipler veya erişim düzenekleri nesne olarak nitelendirilmektedir. Bir cihazın "akıllı" sayılabilmesi ve nesne olarak nitelendirilebilmesi için gerekli şartlar: Tekil bir isme sahip olması (unique id), bağlanılabilir olması ve bir sensörü olmasıdır. Bu sayede, akıllı nesne dünyanın herhangi bir yerinden erişilebilir ve kontrol edilebilir hale gelmektedir. Nesnelerin İnterneti uygulamaları, sensörlerin tek tek erişilebilir olmasından başka, pek çok sensörün verisinin birleştirilerek değer üretilmesi amacıyla da kullanılmaktadır. Fiziksel ortamlardan akarak gelen yüksek miktardaki sensör verilerinin (data), yapılan değerlendirmelerin ardından bilgi (information) olarak operatörlere veya ilgili kişilere iletilmesi ya da verinin sistemler yardımıyla işlenerek bir faaliyet icra edilmesi sağlanmaktadır. Bu açıdan bakıldığında Nesnelerin İnternetinin Büyük Veri kavramları ve uygulamaları ile iç içe olduğu görülmektedir. </p>
                    <img id="zoom" src="images/sw.png" data-zoom-image="images/sw_.jpg" height="253" width="450">


                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) {
                alert('test');
                $('#zoom').ezPlus({
                    zoomType: 'inner',
                    cursor: 'crosshair'
                });
                $("#eng").click(function () {
                    $('#zoom').attr('src', 'images/libelium_smart_world.png');
                    $("#zoom").data('zoom-image', 'images/libelium_smart_world.jpg').ezPlus({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        responsive: "true"

                    });
                });
                $("#tr").click(function () {
                    $('#zoom').attr('src', 'images/sw.png');
                    $("#zoom").data('zoom-image', 'images/sw_.jpg').ezPlus({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        responsive: "true"

                    });
                });
            }
    });
```

But the zoom feature doesn't work!

Here is the zooming js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/igorlino/elevatezoom-plus/1.1.6/src/jquery.ez-plus.js"></script>
```

How can I fix this situation? If I don't check for the active class, this zooming feature starts displaying at the main page which is useless.

**EdiT 1: The screenshot of the main page of the site:**

[main page](http://s13.postimg.org/6immrzgtz/sample1.png)

**The screenshot of the navigated page where zooming should occur**

[navigated page](http://s21.postimg.org/3qgpjid5z/sample2.png)

**EdiT 2: adding img hover makes zoom work for Chrome and IE 11 but unfortunately not for FF. On FF after I click the language choice button zooming works!**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#iot").hover(function () {

            if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) {

                $('#zoom').ezPlus({
                    zoomType: 'inner',
                    cursor: 'crosshair'
                });
                $("#eng").click(function () {
                    $('#zoom').attr('src', 'images/libelium_smart_world.png');
                    $("#zoom").data('zoom-image', 'images/libelium_smart_world.jpg').ezPlus({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        responsive: "true"

                    });
                });
                $("#tr").click(function () {
                    $('#zoom').attr('src', 'images/sw.png');
                    $("#zoom").data('zoom-image', 'images/sw_.jpg').ezPlus({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        responsive: "true"

                    });
                });
            }

        });
    });
```

Here is language selection markup:

```
 <div class="lang">
        <a href="#turkish" onclick="window.lang.change('tr'); return false;"><img src="images/turkey-icon.png" alt="Türkçe" id="tr"></a>
        <a href="#english" onclick="window.lang.change('en'); return false;"><img src="images/uk-icon.png" alt="English" id="eng"></a>

    </div>
```

**Edit 3: removing line below makes zooming works for all browsers!**

```
if ($("#iot").hasClass("active"))
```

Comment: You can assume `hasClass` works just fine, so the problem lays elsewhere. Are you getting any console errors? An earlier error will stop subsequent scripts running.

Comment: How do you load that `section`? Where is `javascript` snippet called? Are you sure that that code is actually called, when you display that section?

Comment: Do you have an element with ID: `iot`?

Comment: @Rajesh: It's in the example HTML (first line)!

Comment: I dont see in your html an element with an id `iot`

Comment: @MoLow: It's in the sample HTML (first line)!

Comment: instead of letting us all guess why don't you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then tell us exactly what "doesn't work" about your script.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: Irrelevant for the example shown (and that one was fixed 3 years ago) :)

Comment: Its working fine. Check following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/cmnhLdy3/)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie there are no errors on console.

Comment: @Pamblam alert message doesn't pop up which means the whole script not working.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.2.

Comment: the code is working. someone above made a jsfiddle to prove it. it's just not doing what *you think* it should be doing. never say "it doesn't work" that's the most obnoxious unhelpful thing you could possibly say.

Comment: @Pamblam please check my edit 1. In the second screenshot I can not zoom the image. Zooming is not working.

Comment: @Pamblam hover image works for IE 11 and Chrome but there is a problem on FF, please check my edit 2

Comment: removing `if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) {` from javascript makes zooming work for all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You're running the code when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Clicking one of your links isn't causing a page navigation event, so the code inside `$(document).ready()` wont run again. (Your links are actually *anchors*.)

Try hooking it up to a `li` click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.navigation li.link').click(function(){
        if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) {
            alert('test');
            $('#zoom').ezPlus({
                zoomType: 'inner',
                cursor: 'crosshair'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This may or may not work depending on what code is adding the `active` class to the `li`. If it doesn't work, try:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.navigation li.link').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) {
                alert('test');
                $('#zoom').ezPlus({
                    zoomType: 'inner',
                    cursor: 'crosshair'
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both but doesn't solve my problem. By the way I am using bootstrap 3.2.

Comment: can I hook it on image hover?

Comment: hover image works for IE 11 and Chrome but there is a problem on FF, please check my edit 2.

Comment: removing if ($("#iot").hasClass("active")) { from javascript makes zooming work for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

this jquery works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#iot").hover(function () {

            $('#zoom').ezPlus({
                    zoomType: 'inner',
                    cursor: 'crosshair'
                });
                $("#eng").click(function () {
                    $('#zoom').attr('src', 'images/libelium_smart_world.png');
                    $("#zoom").data('zoom-image', 'images/libelium_smart_world.jpg').ezPlus({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        responsive: "true"

                    });
                });
                $("#tr").click(function () {
                    $('#zoom').attr('src', 'images/sw.png');
                    $("#zoom").data('zoom-image', 'images/sw_.jpg').ezPlus({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        responsive: "true"

                    });
                });

        });
    });
```